# How to retrieve Firestore data ID on each different Wallpaper?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I found a problem when (all) wallpaper is clicked, then the retrieved data is not the data it should be. Here's the application..

What the app looks like:
[image: 1]

This is my firestore data with different `name` and `secretariat` in each wallpaper:

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

This is the code to retrieve data from the firestore into `textViewContributor` and `textViewSekretariat` located in `FinalWallpaperActivity`

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityInfoBinding
private var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

private lateinit var tvInputKontributor: TextView
private lateinit var tvInputSekretariat: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityInfoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    tvInputKontributor = findViewById(R.id.inputKontributor)
    tvInputSekretariat = findViewById(R.id.inputSekretariat)

    firestore.collection("wallpaper")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")

                if (document != null) {
                    val name = document.data["name"].toString()
                    val sekretariat = document.data["sekretariat"].toString()

                    tvInputKontributor.text = name
                    tvInputSekretariat.text = sekretariat
                }
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }
```

This is the `btnInfo` declaration to open the `InfoActivity`

```
    btnInfo.setOnClickListener {
        val i = Intent(this, InfoActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
    }
```

**How to make each wallpaper have a different info description according to the clicked wallpaper? For my case all wallpapers have the same info description.. Whereas every contributor to the wallpaper should be different**

[image: 6]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: How to make each wallpaper have a different info description according to the clicked wallpaper? for my case all wallpapers have the same info description.. whereas every contributor to the wallpaper should be different @AlexMamo

Comment: Are you passing any info about the wallpaper the user clicked on into the activity?

Comment: I'm confused about how to provide info on each wallpaper with different contributor names @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

you should be learning how to convert from json into array in kotlin ways and you should be working on Parcelable Data Class for eficiency data transfer.

Each pressed button/list item should passing a certain data object includes Contributor, Document ID,etc to a detail screen using Parcelable Data Class.